# 2 apparently identical codes! One compiles, one throws up seg fault

Tags: c, struct, queue

I am a beginning C-programmer, and was just coding for a practice question involving queue operations, and while debugging, I came across the following scenarios:

**Code sample 1**:

```
int dequeue (struct queue_node * Q) {

    struct queue_node * curr = Q->next;
    if(!Q->next)
            return -2;
    else
    {
            int s = Q->next->v_no;
            Q->next = curr->next;
            free(curr);
            return s;
    }

}
```

**Code sample 2 (the same function written in a slightly modified way):**

```
int dequeue (struct queue_node * Q) {

    struct queue_node * curr = Q;
    if(!curr->next)
            return -2;
    else
    {
            int s = curr->next->v_no;
            Q->next = curr->next->next;
            free(curr->next);
            return s;
    }

}
```

**The predefined data-structures are as follows**:

```
struct queue_node {

    int v_no;
    struct queue_node * next;

};

void enqueue (struct queue_node * Q , int s) {

    struct queue_node * curr = Q;
    while (curr->next)
            curr = curr->next;

    curr->next = malloc(sizeof(struct queue_node));
    if(!curr->next)
            exit(10);   //No specific reason for errno 10, just wanted to exit
    curr->next->v_no = s;
    curr->next->next = NULL;

}
```

**The problem:**
Code in the scenario 1 allows the program to execute successfully and output the expected answer but according to my understanding, code in scenario 2 also tries to achieve the same thing, but gives out segmentation fault. Could someone please point out if there is something lacking in my understanding or if I got something wrong in the code itself??

Thanks!

Comment: Please fix the code formatting. The editor has buttons and shortcuts (Ctrl+K) for this.

Comment: Are you sure you want to get rid of the item at `->next`?

Comment: Remember to accept _an_ answer eventually -- doesn't have to be mine, but someone should get some karma out of this. :)

Comment: @Nikos:thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's assume your queue structure currently has three elements:

```
{a} -> {b} -> {c} -> NULL
```

with `Q` currently pointing to `b`.

Let's walk through what each of your functions would do.

```
/* Example 1 (working) */
int dequeue (struct queue_node * Q) {

    struct queue_node * curr = Q->next;    // curr = {c}
    if(!Q->next)                           // c != NULL, so OK
            return -2;
    else
    {
            int s = Q->next->v_no;         // s = c.v_no
            Q->next = curr->next;          // Q->next = NULL
            free(curr);                    // free({c})
            return s;                      // return c.v_no
    }
}
```

So Example 1, provided with a pointer to a Q node, dequeues and removes the next node, returning its `v_no`.

```
/* Example 2 (segfaults) */
int dequeue (struct queue_node * Q) {

    struct queue_node * curr = Q;          // curr now points to the same element as q
    if(!curr->next)                        // {b}->next == {c}, so OK
            return -2;          
    else 
    {
            int s = curr->next->v_no;      // s = Q
            Q->next = curr->next->next;    // Q->next = NULL ({c}->next)
            free(curr->next);              // same as free (Q->next) == free(null)
            return s;
    }

}
```

So in the second example, you free a null pointer -- segfault!

Comment: all of you explained well, just had to choose somebody for the best answers...after all karma cannot be destroyed, it could only get transferred :). Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4):

The issue is where you do the freeing.  Here's the one that works:

```
int s = Q->next->v_no;
Q->next = curr->next;
free(curr);
```

And here's the one that doesn't:

```
int s = curr->next->v_no;
Q->next = curr->next->next;
free(curr->next);
```

Remember, in the second instance, you have `curr` = `Q`.  So, in the first one, we set `Q->next` to `Q->next->next`, and then we remove the *old* `Q->next`.

In the second one, we set `Q->next` to `Q->next->next`, but then we remove the *current* `Q->next`.

Comment: I guess we've all seen it at the same moment

Comment: That's funny, four almost identical answers in the space of a few seconds.

Comment: Funny, it took us each that long to find the answer.

Comment: @scott yes, and I had too look at it for quite a while

Comment: Ingo, Paul, Scott and Christian: Thanks a lot for your clear answers. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

That's the problem in scenario 2:

```
curr = Q;          
...  
Q->next = curr->next->next;   
free(curr->next);
```

Because of `Q == curr` if you set `Q->next` to another pointer, you also change `curr->next`. So the subsequenf `free(curr->next)` doesn't free the dequed element but the new assigned one.

Answer (score 3):

In the second code section, when you do:

```
curr = Q;
```

and then:

```
Q->next = curr->next->next;
```

`Q` and `curr` are pointing to the same thing, so when you change `Q->next`, you're also changing `curr->next`, and your call to `free(curr->next)` goes awry.

In the first code section, `curr` is set to `Q->next` at the beginning, not to `Q`, so when you change `Q->next`, `curr` remains unaffected, and so you `free()` the correct pointer.

Comment: I guess we've all seen it at the same moment

Answer (score 0):

Below line cause problem

```
 Q->next = curr->next->next;
```

Because Q and curr is the same pointer, after that assignment, Q->next can be null (if your queue had only one element). So, when you call

```
free(curr->next);
```

you are trying to free null. There also logical error, you never free dequeued elements.

Comment: in this line curr->next is pointer to third element from top of queue